# Saving initial data as a date format (like 2012-02) using a YAML file in Play Framework

Tags: datetime, playframework, yaml

In Play framework, my model code looks like;

```
@Entity
public class Student extends Model {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Finder<Long, Student> find = new Finder<Long, Student>(
            Long.class, Student.class);
...
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "YYYY-MM")
    public Date career_begin;
```

As you can see, career_begin is defined as dateTime format like 'yyyy-mm'.

Then, I tried to save my initial data through YAML file. It looks like;

```
students:
            - !!models.Student
                     ...
                     career_begin: 2010-02
```

However, this data cannot be read by Play framework. It keeps saying that it is an invalid input. How can I put date format data in YAML file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a valid YAML date format, the `@Formats.DateTime` is not used by the YAML parser. The list of valid formats are here - http://yaml.org/type/timestamp.html

For your example, you should be able to use the following

```
2012-02-01
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to add quotes to make it work. Example:
  students:
    career_begin: '2013-10-11'
    created_at: '2012-10-03 12:53:17'